# How to build two .env files depending on variable

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I have two .env files (.env.development and .env.production) and two different build scripts, one for dev and one for prod. Now I want exactly one build script and depending on a global environment variable I want to decide what of this two .env files should be used for the build.

Is there a way to write in a build script a checker on what the environment variable is set ?

Comment: Which platform are you using for production?

Comment: What do you mean what platform ?

Comment: I mean in production where do you serve the app, Heroku, AWS etc

Comment: On a normal unix server with apache. The problem is, that I have two build scripts and I want exactly one, but the NODE_ENV variable should decide what file should be used at the build

Comment: May I ask what unix server, Ubuntu, CenOS or something else, I'm asking because there will be ways to set env variables to OS?

Comment: I need my configs in .env files. The only variable I want to set in the OS is what .env file should be used

Comment: I understand, there is a way that I did in the past but it is a little bit wrong because you expose env variables to your os environment and it is application specific so I used Docker instead of installing app to OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can solve this problem by passing environmental variables from your unix server in production, but when in development pass it from .env file, this way you don't need to add twi build scripts because it will get variables from .env or from unix env.

To pass env variables to your Node.js app from Unix OS is like

Open Terminal and write the command as

```sh
> export MY_ENV=my environment value
```

After that you will see the env variable with

```sh
> echo "$MY_ENV"
```

But I suggest you to use Docker and set the env variables to your Docker env this way you will separate your env variables from OS env and prevent inconsistencies